# Ajax Crawlable site - Get HTML Snapshot using WaTin

Tags: ajax, watin, asp.net-mvc-4, google-crawlers

Id like to use Watin to get html snapshots to make my single page ajax app crawlable as per google specifications.

Can somebody please show me code example how to return an html snapshot to googlebot using Watin?

This is what I have so far but honestly Im not even sure where Im going with this I really havent found a single example on the web that would really clear it up:

Controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult Solutions()
    {
        //Googlebot request
        HtmlString htmlSnapshot = (HtmlString)GetHtmlSnapshot(Request.Path);
        //return ?????????

        //Normal user request
        return PartialView("Solutions", null);
    }
    public PartialViewResult MarketData()
    {
        return PartialView("MarketData", null);
    }

    public IHtmlString GetHtmlSnapshot(string uglyUrl)
    {
        if (uglyUrl.Contains("?_escaped_fragment_="))
        {
            string prettyUrl = uglyUrl.Replace("?_escaped_fragment=", "");
            string decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(prettyUrl);

            FireFox firefox = new FireFox();
            firefox.GoTo(decodedUrl);

            //?????????                
        }            
    }
```